# Windows 10 Sticky Notes Can't Type

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

I am using windows 10 sticky notes and when I make a sticky note then type some stuff eventually it seems to almost become read only.

when I try to type something in it won't let me, but I can delete stuff or cut stuff but can't type anything new.

I feel like this is because I have the feature that syncs on (don't know how to turn it off).

Edit

Windows 10 Pro: 10.0.18362 Build 18362

Stick Version: 3.7.7.1.0

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have installed?  What version of the stick notes application do you have installed?  Please edit your question to include this vital information instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: "I feel like this is because I have the feature that syncs on" - You can signout of your Microsoft Account by going to Settings within Sticky Notes.  However, your inability to create a new note is unrelated to yout sync status.

Comment: I updated with Windows Version and Sticky Version. I can create new notes, I can delete existing notes, I can delete the content from existing notes but I cannot add content to existing notes.

Comment: Are you synching your notes with a Microsoft Account? Have you tried logging out of that account and logging back into it?

Comment: My workaround is to simply close sticky notes and reopen it.
But I hate this bug as well, has been driving me nuts for months...

Comment: I just gave up on it, I downloaded some other one from the store, it is not that great but at least I don't have to close and copy to a new card every day.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, and like @Marko says, only way I've found is to close and reopen notes.

Comment: FFS how can they have such a terrible bug in such a simple piece of software?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well, I am logged into my computer, I will RDP into my computer from a remote location as the same user I am logged in as, close the RDP session, return to my desk and am unable to type in StickyNotes. My work around is to use Ctrl+A, to select all text, Ctrl+X to cut the text, start a new sticky not using the plus icon in sticky notes, paste the text into a new note and am able to type again...

Comment: I never could find a solution to my problem, I turned of syncing and still ran into the problem. I downloaded some 3rd party one and am using it instead.